# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at compute

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

I have some code that returns an `Uncaught SyntaxError` when I run it but I don't understand why.

I tried putting it through JSHint but to no avail.

Here is the code that is apparently wrong:

```
function compute(expr, x, string) {
  var whatisx = "x=" + toString(x) + ",";
  var tempAns = parseFloat(eval(whatisx + expr));
  var roundedAnswer = roundNumber(tempAns, 3);
  if (isNaN(tempAns) === true) {
    alert("error");
  }
  if (string) {
    return toString(roundedAnswer);
  } else if (!string) {
    return roundedAnswer;
  } else {
    return null;
    console.log("Error trying to compute value. The string value must be boolean.");
  }
}
```

When I run it, I don't get any console logs and it says there is an error at the plus sign in:

```
var tempAns = parseFloat(eval(whatisx + expr));
```

Another problem in the same program that is also a SyntaxError is in my HTML.

Here is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grapher</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label>Graph y=</label>
      <input id="mathExpr" type="text" name="mathExpr" value="">
      <label> from x=</label>
      <input id="x_min" type="text" name="x_min" value="">
      <label> to </label>
      <input id="x_max" type="text" name="x_max" value="">
      <input type="button" name="result" value="Result" onclick="compute(); runp5();">
    </form>
    <h2>Answer: <span id="output"></span></h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

For this one, it says there is an error at

```
<input type="button" name="result" value="Result" onclick="compute(); runp5();">
```

What can I do to fix both of those?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Question resolved. I was calling compute without any parameters. (thanks @Pointy)

Comment: You're calling `compute()` without passing any parameters, even though the function clearly expects some.

Comment: `eval(whatisx + expr)` yikes

Comment: What parameters are you calling compute() with which causes the `Uncaught SyntaxError`?

Comment: I was calling it with no parameters and it was supposed to have 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came back to this question just now, and I realized I was making another mistake. Here is my fix:

1. As user Pointy noticed, I was calling `compute()` without its required parameters.
2. I should add `console.log()` in my `else` statement before the `return` otherwise it won't get called at all:

```js
// ...

else {
  console.log('message'); // this should come before return
  return null;
}
```

This doesn't actually fix the problem I detailed, but I wanted to point it out for any future readers.