# Simple JS Example not running (Click of a button)

Tags: javascript, html

Why this JS example is not running? Can anyone tell me?

```js
alpha(ev){
  console.log(ev);
}
```

```css
.red {background:red;}
.blue{background:blue;}
```

```html
<button onclick=alpha()>ok</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at compute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654859/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-at-compute)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass ev as a parameter to your function

<`button onclick=alpha(ev)>ok</button>`

You also need to place keyword `function` before the function name, so your code will be something like this :

```
function alpha(ev) { console.log(ev);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass an `ev` argument to `alpha()`:

```js
function alpha(ev) {
  console.log(ev);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alpha('somevalue')">ok</button>
```